# MVC 4 Form Issue missing form method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On an edit page for users I have a block to allow me or other admins to edit a users role. This is the code in the edit.cshtml

```
                    <tr>
                    @foreach (var role in roles) 
                    {
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("UserInRole", "Member"))
                    { 
                      <input type="hidden" value = "@user"  name="username" />
                      <input type="hidden" value= "@role" name="rolename" />
                      <input type="hidden" value="@id" name="id" />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="ischecked" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="true" checked="@System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(@Model.PrimaryEmail, role)" />
                    }
                    </td>
                    }
                    </tr>
```

When the page displays I get the following result when looking at it with Firebug:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="cxxxx.xxxxxxxn@xxxxxxxxxx.com">
<input type="hidden" name="rolename" value="Admin">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="365">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" onclick="this.form.submit();" name="ischecked">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center">
<form method="post" action="/Member/UserInRole" novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="xxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com">
<input type="hidden" name="rolename" value="MediaAdmin">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="365">
<input type="checkbox" value="true" onclick="this.form.submit();" name="ischecked">
</form>
```

Notice the form tag missing from the first

Not understanding why this is happening.

Comment: I have used your code, it is working fine on my side. FORM getting generated as per iterations. Can you see if some other part of the code is messing up?

Comment: I'll take a look through everything just in case.

Comment: I was not able to find anything else that was causing this to happen.  I split this out to a separate page and it worked fine.  Still not sure why it happened, doesn't matter now.